# Not getting any output after reading in from file

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int length [48];
    int us[48];
    int russ[38];

    ifstream infile;

    infile.open("data.txt");
    if(infile.fail())
    {
        cout << "error" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<48;i++)
    {
        infile >> length[i];
        infile >> us[i];
        while(i<=38)
        {
            infile>> russ[i];
        }
        infile.close();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
    {
        cout << length[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to read each column above from a text file into a corresponding array. First column is length, second is us, third is russ. When i try to do a sample output to test it nothing is coming out. The program is compiling completely without bugs or errors but it is just not displaying the output.

Comment: `while(i<=38)...` Infinite loop.

Comment: edit your code so it is more readable.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Ah yeah! You are right! Sorry, my mistake

Comment: how is your text file info? from your code you wanna have for each line 3 col, first: integer, second: integer and third is an array of integer with 38 elements. is that correct?

Comment: `infile.close();` closes stream before 2nd iteration of `for(int i=0;i<48;i++)`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here

```
while(i<=38)
{
   infile>> russ[i];
}
```

simply replace it with this:

```
while(i<38)
{

   infile>> russ[i++];
}
```

Also, I don't know what you're trying to do exactly, since you're producing your output after too many for loops, therefore you're losing your data.

Comment: It has to be only less `while(i<38)`, because `int russ[38];` contains 38 elements not 39.

Comment: @AlexeyUsachov I focused on the infinite loop and forgot the AoB. Thanks